# Praat - window size larger than vowel

Tags: corpora, vowels, praat

I'm doing an acoustic-phonetic analysis of read-speech in an American English corpus.
If we want to set a window/frame size (25 - 30 ms) to cover the majority of vowels in the corpus, but some vowels (in rapid speech) are smaller in duration -- then does Praat automatically adjust to one-frame only in such cases? I don't want to lose them, because data is sparse anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Praat doesn't automatically adjust, or have any idea about vowels versus consonants. Also, the window size is set by the individual analysis, so there isn't a one-size universal window. I can't think of a context where a window size as big as 25 msc would be correct. I *think* your question is, what does Praat do if the duration is the selection is too short, given the requested analysis. The manual on Sound: To Spectrogram is somewhat informative

> For purposes of computation speed, Praat may decide to change the time
>   step and the frequency step. This is because the time step never needs
>   to be smaller than 1/(8√π) of the window length, and the frequency
>   step never needs to be smaller than (√π)/8 of the inverse of the
>   window length. For instance, if the window length is 29 ms, the actual
>   time step will be never be less than 29/(8√π) = 2.045 ms. And if the
>   window length is 5 ms, the actual frequency step will never be less
>   than (√π)/8/0.005 = 44.31 Hz.

It seems you have to read the details of the particular analysis to see how Praat deals with hyper-short windows.